No entry in user_change_notification_regs table
I am writing an app to get notification from oracle database when data in a table changes.
I am using oracle continuous query notification for it.
As i understand from document, when we call registerDatabaseChangeNotification method on an oracle connection, it will create an entry in user_change_notification_regs table.
I tried to query the table after call to method registerDatabaseChangeNotification.
The table was blank. there was no entry in the table.

Are you connected to the schema from which registration was created?
If from different schema you can check DBA_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS table and see if it returns any rows.
